# How do I stream/allow skipping around for an OGV file from a webserver?

Tags: video-streaming, webserver, ogg

I know this may be a bit generic, so any help or direction would be helpful. Here's the situation:

I'm writing an addon for Firefox to swap out khanacademy.org videos for "local" versions for use in situations where the user has much less bandwidth or is far from the khanacademy servers (think Africa). The extension part is relatively straightforward. It replaces the video with an HTML 5  tag and points to a `.ogv` file on a local server.

Ideally I could set up a lightweight server that would allow the user to "stream" the video so they can jump around in video playback and not have to wait for the entire file to download. I've set up nginx to serve the video files as static files, and they appear to download progressively, however if I jump to another part of the video, it stops playing and the video appears to break.

So my question boils down to is there a way to set up a server (hopefully easy to setup and runs on Ubuntu) that'll allow for skipping around the video?

Answer (score 0):

[Flumotion](http://www.flumotion.net/) is able to stream `.ogv` files and allows seeking to arbitrary positions during playback. I installed it on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS by running `sudo apt-get install flumotion` and was able to get the above scenario working.